# Python mysql doesn't see data change in database

Tags: python, mysql

i need some help with python an mysql.

I have the following code, which is executing in infinite loop:

```
db = MySQLdb.connect("127.0.0.1","user","password","dbname" )
while True:
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM requests WHERE status <> 'Finished'")
    all_pending_requests = cursor.fetchall()
    cursor.close()
```

And that works fine the first time i run it. But when i go to a tool like mysql workbench or i type it myself in in terminal, i update some rows and set their status to something that is not "Finished". So by doing that the next time the loop executes i should get those rows as a result but i get nothing. Do you guys now why this is happening maybe?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Does MySQL need to be committed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not certain but would assume that you are using InnoDB storage engine in MySQL and MySQLdb version >=1.2.0. You need to commit before the changes are being reflected. As of version 1.2.0, MySQLdb disables auto-commit by default. Confirmation of the same is [here](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/FAQ.html#my-data-disappeared-or-won-t-go-away). Try adding `db.commit()` as the last line in  the loop.